# Aggregate age groups in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aggregation, data-manipulation

I am having trouble aggregating some data and I hoped that you guys could shed some light!

The data I have is quite a complex set of data and I would wish to aggregate the age groups together.

the age groups I am looking for are: under 25, between 25 and 45, between 45 and 55, and over 55.

the code I had though of using is:

```
age_categories = {1:'<25', 2:'<25', 3:'<25'...} 

cust_data['age'] = [age[x] for x in cust_data['age']] cust_data['age'].value_counts()
```

There must surely be a way of using `pd.groupby` put I just cannot find it.

I would appriciate the help!

Comment: Yes, you want `groupby` with `pd.cut`: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990218/grouping-column-values-together. Just need to specify your bin edges [-np.inf, 25, 45, 55, np.inf]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Groupby Range of Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441259/pandas-groupby-range-of-values)

Comment: I've tried that already but i get the following error: arange() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)